# TF-lite model test fails with run-time Error

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I have created a TF-lite model for MNIST classification (I am using TF 1.12.0 and running this on Google Colab) and I want to test it using TensorFlow Lite Python interpreter as given in

https://github.com/freedomtan/tensorflow/blob/deeplab_tflite_python/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/python/label_image.py

But I am getting this error when I try to invoke the interpreter -

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-7d35ed1dfe14> in <module>()
----> 1 interpreter.invoke()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter.py in invoke(self)
251       ValueError: When the underlying interpreter fails raise 
ValueError.
252     """
--> 253     self._ensure_safe()
254     self._interpreter.Invoke()
255 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter.py in 
_ensure_safe(self)
 97       in the interpreter in the form of a numpy array or slice. Be sure 
 to
 98       only hold the function returned from tensor() if you are using 
 raw
 ---> 99       data access.""")

101   def _get_tensor_details(self, tensor_index):

 RuntimeError: There is at least 1 reference to internal data
  in the interpreter in the form of a numpy array or slice. Be sure to
  only hold the function returned from tensor() if you are using raw
  data access.
```

Here is the code -

```
import numpy as np

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = 
tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path="mnist/mnist_custom.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_details
```

[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 3,
  'name': 'conv2d_1_input',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'shape': array([ 1, 28, 28,  1], dtype=int32)}]

```
test_images[0].shape
```

(28, 28, 1)

```
input_data = np.expand_dims(test_images[0], axis=0)
input_data.shape
```

(1, 28, 28, 1)

```
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
```

The problem is I do not understand what this message means and what to do about it.

Comment: OK.. fixed this ..added input_tensor= tf.convert_to_tensor(input_data, np.float32) then interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

Comment: Hi! Do you mind elaborating on your solution? I'm facing the same problem and I'm not sure how to solve it

Comment: Wither (i) restart jupyter notebook or (ii) re-loading the model works for me. Check the detailed explanation in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777704/how-to-fix-there-is-at-least-1-reference-to-internal-data-in-the-interpreter-in

Answer (score 2):

`tf.convert_to_tensor` and `interpreter.set_tensor` did the job for me

```
tensor_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
input_tensor_z= tf.convert_to_tensor(z, np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(tensor_index, input_tensor_z)
```

I've created an end2end example starting from training a Keras model to serve it on TensorFlow Lite [here](https://github.com/romeokienzler/TensorFlow/blob/master/notebooks/tf2savedModel.ipynb)

I've also posted the same answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777704/how-to-fix-there-is-at-least-1-reference-to-internal-data-in-the-interpreter-in/60403076#60403076) thread